# How to parse Jmeter response and make a new request

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jMeter to test a Tomcat application. I need to parse the jMeter response and make a second request. The first response looks like this:

```
<responseData class="java.lang.String">&lt;html&gt;&#xd;
&lt;body&gt;&#xd;
ERROR=0&#xd;
MSG=N/A&#xd;
FILELIST=1555;1340778737370;1526545487;&#xd;
VERSION=1.002&#xd;
URL=https://192.168.100.46/updserver/download?action=signature_download&amp;token=&#xd;
INTERVAL=0&#xd;
&lt;/body&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/html&gt;&#xd;
</responseData>
```

I need to extract the "FILELIST" and "URL" variables and inject them into a new URL:

```
https://192.168.100.46/updserver/download?action=signature_download&amp;token=1555;1340778737370;1526545487;&#xd;
```

I know there is some post-processor to do that, but no clue how to do it. BTW, the second request will download some file from the Tomcat servlet, is there a way to let jMeter just download the stream but without writing to a physical file? So that I could do a load performance test against my servlet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok so you already know how to extract url out of your response, I described how in my previous answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11188349/169277

But here I'll just expand on that. So you have your sampler and you already got $`{url}`. Now you need `FILELIST` and assemble new url.

Assuming you already have request and url extractor in place. Add a new `Regular expression extractor`.

`Right click on request sampler -> Post Processors -> Regular Expression Extractor`

```
Reference Name : FILELIST
Regular Expression : FILELIST=(\S+)
Template : $1$
Match No. (0 for Random): 1
```

So now you have 1 request sampler and 2 regular expression extractors. You need to add additional post processor to be able to assemble the new url.

`Right click on request sampler -> Post Processors -> BSF PostProcessor`

Choose the `beanshell` from the language droplist under the `Script language` and in the big field `Script:` paste this :

```
vars.put("NEW_URL", "${__javaScript('${url}'.replace('&#xd;'\,'${FILELIST}'))}");
```

And now you have `${NEW_URL}` to use further in your tests.

**There is always more than one way of solving problems, this one liner looks really ugly but it serves the purpose.**

In my test the result is as you requested (Debug Sampler) :

```
url=https://192.168.100.46/updserver/download?action=signature_download&amp;token=&#xd;
FILELIST=1555;1340778737370;1526545487;&#xd;
NEW_URL=https://192.168.100.46/updserver/download?action=signature_download&amp;token=1555;1340778737370;1526545487;&#xd;
```

**EDIT :**

I think I don't understand how you name your variables. But the end result is the one you described in your question. Please see the .jmx test attached with working example :

http://www.filefactory.com/file/1q7nfitmh4qd/n/so_11309469_jmx

It's a jmeter .jmx file working with 2.6+ version of jmeter

Comment: @ ant, according to your help,currently i have sample1(which have 3 post processor:url/token extrator/bsf post-processor), and sample2 for send new request. But still some error that the sample2 does not get the correct URL, Please help to find my Debug Sampler: [link]http://pastebin.com/rXB00uTL

Comment: @ ant, i'm sorry that i made a terrible mistake.It worked on my side now, i can not appreciate more to you for your great help.

Answer (score 7):

To [capture](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) part of the response use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

You can test your regex expression on response data using ViewResultsTree listener. Just select Regexp tester in the drop-down box at the bottom of the left hand panel in your ViewResultsTree listener.