# Get multiple values from filter URL via regex on ecommerce site randomly in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

For example I have this URL like

```
http://www.example.com/search?text=soda&show=Page&layoutStatus=grid&categoryCode=&q=soda%3Arelevance&terms=%3ACalories%3A0+Cal
```

I need to fetch the values:

> %3A**Calories**%3A**0+Cal**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse Jmeter response and make a new request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306584/how-to-parse-jmeter-response-and-make-a-new-request)

Comment: i have tried this. this is not working. i need to fetch only above 2 values randomly. rest of url is same.i have tried this regex but not working. <input id="terms" type="hidden" name="terms" value=":(.+?):(.+?)"> and this is its  url after decode: /search?text=soda&show=Page&layoutStatus=grid&categoryCode=&q=soda:relevance&terms=:Calories:0 Cal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Create a regex repression like: href="/product(.+?).uts\?swatchName=(.+?)"
where (.+?) is appearing 2 times for a 2 variables. and pass parameter like ${value_g1} and ${value_g2} in the url. resolved issue.