# Jmeter - Test for login/logout of a wordpress site - Failing for logout

Tags: wordpress, jmeter, logout

It turns out that for every login there is a new NONCE value generated.

I am having a hard time finding how to get this dynamic value upon successful login and use it in the url parameter for logout. %site_url%/logout/?_wpnonce= in Jmeter. If I don't pass this parameter I get a 403 from my webserver. Its a protection from CSRF attacks.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite a common situation. Check answers for this [How to parse Jmeter response and make a new request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306584/how-to-parse-jmeter-response-and-make-a-new-request) question or try [SmartMeter's automatic correlation feature](http://How%20to%20parse%20Jmeter%20response%20and%20make%20a%20new%20request). It works the same but fits better for scenarios when you need to use the token multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Find which page response is originally generating the dynamic url, then use a regular expression extractor. Whatever you use for the reference name in the regex extractor, use that in your url.  It will dynamically be generated every time it goes through.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html
https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jmeter