# Difference between params and post request parameters in Firebug ang how to pass them through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, firebug

In Firebug post request details shows some data under "params" and "post" tab.

param data pass through the path and parameters under the "post" tab pass through the parameters in Jmeter.

one param data that shows in firebug is dynamically generated for each session.
how to get that value in the path and pass to other http request path.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you have to extract a dynamic data to a variable and use that later in another request. If this is the case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522272/1843163) should give more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'params' tab shows the GET requests, and the 'post' tab shows the POST requests, according https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel